# Installing Hashcat v3.10 Ubuntu error

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, hashcat

I was following this tutorial [hashcat turtorial](http://techglimpse.com/password-cracking-with-hashcat/), obviously changing/updating commands where necessary. And I have encountered various problems.

When I input the help command it responds fully as can be seen in this short quote

> cadiz@cadiz:~$ 
>   hashcat64.bin --help
>
> hashcat, advanced password recovery
>
> Usage: hashcat [options]... hash|hashfile|hccapfile [dictionary|mask|directory]...

However when I input a proper command this is what happens:

> cadiz@cadiz:~$ hashcat64.bin -m 0 -a 1 Desktop/md5ex.txt Desktop/realuniq.lst -r hashcat-3.10/rules/combinator.rule
>
> ERROR: /usr/bin/OpenCL/: No such file or directory

I have no idea what the problem is here at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the OpenCL runtime. Check the mainpage of hashcat.net

- AMD users on Windows require "AMD Radeon Software Crimson Edition" (15.12 or later)
- AMD users on Linux require "AMDGPU-Pro Driver" (16.40 or later)
- Intel CPU users require "OpenCL Runtime for Intel Core and Intel Xeon Processors" (16.1.1 or later)
- Intel GPU on Windows users require "OpenCL Driver for Intel Iris and Intel HD Graphics"
- Intel GPU on Linux users require "OpenCL 2.0 GPU Driver Package for Linux" (2.0 or later)
- NVidia users require "NVIDIA Driver" (367.x or later)

Answer (score 0):

It is one misleading Error!

It happens maybe/because you entered this command :

```
$ sudo cp [path to Hashcat dir]/hashcat64.bin /usr/bin/
```

And then :

```
$ hashcat64.bin [rest of the command]
```

and I guess, this binary file have some relational link which can be broken when you do that and some permission issues accessing drivers and that tutorial didn't think it through.

So you can run it inside the Hashcat directory, like :

```
[Inside Hashcat dir]$ sudo ./hashcat64.bin [rest of the command]
```

and it will run and detect drivers.

It solved my problem, hope this help.